# How to get task id using OpenOLAT rest api

Tags: java, api, rest

Good day. I can't find how to get task id or task list with parameters in OpenOLAT rest api. 
I need to get list of tasks of current user of some course, choose some task which I need and do final submit of this task using client app based on java. But I don't know how to get list of tasks and how to identify tasks.

Comment: What have tried? Your post could be improved if you included what code you're currently tried. Also, as written your post might be too broadly written for SO.

Comment: If I knew I would not ask. I can give you link to api: https://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwi3yYjtnoLHAhVFKXIKHQcyDYk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhg.openolat.org%2Fopenolat%2Fraw-file%2Ftip%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Folat%2Frestapi%2Fapi%2F_content%2Fapplication.html&ei=Asa5VbfAGMXSyAOH5LTICA&usg=AFQjCNHqNy_WfgXv6Fx-Aiecq7YYxXu69A&sig2=0uBOBpG8SkcjS4bDe_kukw&bvm=bv.99028883,d.bGQ&cad=rja

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by task? The task course element or a test?

Are you referring to the new task element in OpenOLAT 10.3 or the old one from previous versions? In 10.3 the task element has been rewritten from scratch.